# save data from listview to database

Tags: android, listview

I have data from listview, and I want to save it in my database, here's my code;

```
listResep = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listResep);
int leng = listResep.getCount();
for(int i = 0; i < leng; i++) {
    resep = listResep.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    new inputResep().execute();
}
```

and for inputResep;

```
class inputResep extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(InputRM.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("save Resep..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rm", rm));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("noregis", noregis));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tanggal", tglinput));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pukul", pukul));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ruper", ruper));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("kelas", kelas));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("profesi", profesi));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("kajian", resep));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_user", id_user));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tglsave", tglsave));
        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_INPUT_RESEP,"POST", params);

        // check log cat for response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            Log.d("stat", success+"");
            if (success > 0) {
                // successfully created product

            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("test", "JSONException"+e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

but every time I tried to input resep, it only save last data from listview as much as data in listview, ex= `listview: data1, data2, data3; save: data3, data3, data3;`

Comment: i guess you should move you asynctask out of for loop.

Comment: Why are you executing your Async Task several times inside your Loop ?

Comment: Very wrong use of `AsyncTask`, What you should do is utilize Param part of `AsyncTask`. Generate Params and pass them in your `AsyncTask` and access them in `doInBackground()` and then upload your data as a whole or may be in chuknks. And BTW using this technique you need to execute `AsyncTask` once.

Comment: i think use the for loop in the asyncTask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the whole thing in a FOR LOOP, getting the size of the total views in listview and so for each loop the data will be uploaded in the database!!

Comment: This is not answer, rather a comment!

Comment: if the person who asked this question says that it's not helpful, then I will even delete this

Comment: @Kumar Gaurav Totally agreed??

Answer (score 2):

after looking at @Exeptional answer, this is how I deal with it;

```
    int leng = listResep.getCount();
    Log.d("jml resep", ""+leng);
    for(int i = 0; i < leng; i++) {
        resep = listResep.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

        Log.d("save resep"+i, resep);
//      new inputResep().execute();
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rm", rm));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("noregis", noregis));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tanggal", tglinput));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pukul", pukul));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ruper", ruper));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("kelas", kelas));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("profesi", profesi));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("kajian", resep));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_user", id_user));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tglsave", tglsave));
        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_INPUT_RESEP,"POST", params);

        // check log cat for response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            Log.d("stat", success+"");
            if (success > 0) {
                // successfully created product

            } else {
                // failed to create product

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("test", "JSONException"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

it works fine when I tried with emulator, then I tried install in my tablet, at first it works fine, but it didn't work when I tried to save data, so I changed it and put loop in the asyncTask:

```
class inputResep extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        int leng = listResep.getCount();
        Log.d("jml resep", ""+leng);
        for(int i = 0; i < leng; i++) {
            resep = listResep.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rm", rm));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("noregis", noregis));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tanggal", tglinput));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pukul", pukul));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ruper", ruper));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("kelas", kelas));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("profesi", profesi));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("kajian", resep));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_user", id_user));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tglsave", tglsave));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_INPUT_RESEP,"POST", params);

            Log.d("testinput", "4");
            // check log cat for response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                Log.d("stat", success+"");
                if (success > 0) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Log.d("test", "berhasil simpan resep");

                } else {
                    // failed to create product

                    Log.d("test", "failed to create product ");
                }

                Log.d("test", "in try");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("test", "JSONException"+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try useing this one in postexecute in forloop

```
protected void onPostExecute(response response) {
    pDialog.dismiss();


 try {
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        Log.d("stat", success+"");
        if (success > 0) {
            // successfully created product

        } else {
            // failed to create product
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("test", "JSONException"+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```