# save data listview peritem in android

Tags: android, mysql, listview, insert

hei guys, i want insert data from my listview to mysql database per item, but i dont know.

here my code

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_pemesanan);

    final PesananAdapter adapter = new PesananAdapter(this, 
            DatabaseTemp.getPesanan(), DatabaseTemp.getJumlah(),
            DatabaseTemp.getBayar());
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    listView = getListView();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalBayar);
    textView.setText("Total "+ getTotal());
    String total = textView.getText().toString();
    Button buttonPesan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPesan);
    buttonPesan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // kirim data ke server

            new sendToServer().execute();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Pesanan telah dikirim", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // buat databasenya menjadi null kembali

            popup();
        }
    }); 
}

String listPesan() {
String pesan = "";
for (int i = 0; i < DatabaseTemp.getPesanan().size(); i++) {
    pesan += "" + DatabaseTemp.getPesanan().get(i)+",";
}

String pesanan = pesan.substring(0, pesan.length() - 1);
return pesanan;
} 
class sendToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListPesanan.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(ListPesanan.this);
    meja = preferences.getString("meja", "");
    date = new Date();
    dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH");
    String Id_meja = meja.toString();
    String Id_menu = listPesan();
    String Jumlah = DatabaseTemp.getJumlah().toString();
    String harga = DatabaseTemp.getBayar().toString();
    String Tanggal = dateFormat.format(date);
    List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Id_meja", Id_meja));
    list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Id_menu", Id_menu));
    list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Jumlah", Jumlah));
    list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("harga", Harga));
    list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Tanggal", Tanggal));

    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_SERVER,
            "POST", list);

    Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

    try {
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        if (success == 1) {
            DatabaseTemp.delete();              
        } else {
            // failed to create product
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog once done
    pDialog.dismiss();
}}

}
```

my output in database

id(1) pesanan(a,b) jumlah(1,1) harga(10,5) tanggal(13/07/2014)

note #id(auto increment)

and i want output like this

id(1) pesanan(a) jumlah(1) harga(10) tanggal(13/07/2014)

id(1) pesanan(b) jumlah(1) harga(5) tanggal(13/07/2014)

Comment: solve, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371732/save-data-from-listview-to-database